# В mysql вместо NULL в таблице появляются нули

Tags: mysql

Вот таким кодом я изменил дефолтное значение в mysql:

```
ALTER TABLE `social`.`list_of_users` 
CHANGE COLUMN `followers` `followers` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `friends` `friends` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

В таблице в поле дефолтного значения указывается NULL, в самой таблице `'0'`

Comment: изменение типа/default значения колонки ни как не меняет ее содержимого. если до этого в колонке были нули - они там и останутся. default распространяется только на новые записи и только в случае если при вставке данное поле вообще не указано в списке устанавливаемых колонок

Comment: Если нужно убрать эти нули и заменить их на Null (если Вы придали нулевому значению некий смысл, отличающийся от смысла значения Null) - выполните замену запросом на обновление, типа `UPDATE list_of_users SET followers=Null WHERE followers=0;`, и отдельно таким же запросом для поля `friends`.